# How can compare value of two table?

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

I have two data frame like below, I would like to compare value of these table together (based on same rows and colnames) and specified same values with TRUE otherwise with FALSE.

```
data1:

      id              A               B              C
      m1              2               2              2
      m2              2               1              2

data2:

      id              A               D              B
      m1              1               2              2
      m2              2               3              2


Output:

      id                  A             B
      m1              FALSE          TRUE
      m2              TRUE          FALSE
```

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: In fact, nothing. This problem was a bit difficult for me....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `merge` the two data frames after `melt`ing by `id` to find the intersecting columns. Then generate a new column with the equality condition for the values. Finally `dcast` back to wide format for your output table:

```
library(reshape2)
df1 <- melt(data1,"id")
df2 <- melt(data2,"id")
df3 <- merge(df1,df2,by=c("id","variable"))
df3$value <- df3$value.x == df3$value.y
result <- dcast(df3, id~variable)
##id     A     B
##1 m1 FALSE  TRUE
##2 m2  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 5):

Create an index of column names that are common in both datasets, subset the datasets based on that and do the comparison (`==`)

```
nm1 <- intersect(names(data1), names(data2))
cbind(data1[1], data1[nm1][-1]==data2[nm1][-1])
#   id     A     B
#1 m1 FALSE  TRUE
#2 m2  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Fails if `id`s are not in the same order.

Comment: @m0h3n  In the OP's post, there is no info about whether the ids are not in the same order.

Comment: Yes, the point that how proposed solutions would work in situations other than OP's described has always been controversial, I'd say. But assuming that `id`s are strictly in the same order is a strong one.

Comment: @m0h3n  Well, sometimes we have to go for specific situations instead of a generic one if it is easier to implement.